# Moment.js adds 5 years

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, fullcalendar, momentjs

I have a start time and end time, which is passed to form from a fullCalendar dragevent.
I need to be able to change start/end time via a textbox.

function:

```
$("#startt").on("change", function() {
    console.log("CH")
    $("#phpstart").val(
        moment($("#phpstart").val(), "YY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss").format("YYYY-MM-DD") +
        " " +
        moment($(this).val(), "HH:mm").format("HH:mm:ss"))
})
```

After the first change, everything is OK. But after the second change, I got + 5 years.
Picture:
http://p1.pichost.me/i/73/1975986.png

UPDATE
error is in

```
format("YYYY-MM-DD")
```

+5 change occurs, when YY is formated to YYYY, after second firing of function

Comment: So, you have your answer?

Comment: If you've isolated the problem to a bug in the script, it might be helpful to set up an issue on the library's github page. Be sure to include steps to reproduce, a jsfiddle would be super too.

Comment: Sounds to me like `$('#phpstart').val()` is not `YY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss`

Comment: yes maybe reading the 20xx of the year as the xx15 part, hence gaining 5 years.

Comment: It's not an error in the library, your logic is just bad, see my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code reads that `$('#phpstart').val()` should be of the format `YY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss`:

```
moment($("#phpstart").val(), "YY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss")
```

But then you are setting `$('#phpstart').val()` to a format of `YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss` here:

```
$('#phpstart.val(
        moment($("#phpstart").val(), "YY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss").format("YYYY-MM-DD") +
        " " +
        moment($(this).val(), "HH:mm").format("HH:mm:ss"))
);
```

Which is why it is breaking, specifically after the very first change. Keep a consistent format always so that the format of the date in `$('#phpstart').val()` is **always** the same.

Comment: Yes, I kind of figured it out, after experimenting ! But anyways, why still +5

Comment: Because you are telling `momentjs` that a date the looks like `2015-01-01 12:00:00` is of format `YY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss`, and `momentjs` tries to parse it as such. You can imagine that it reads `2015` as `20` (because it only expects a two digit year), and when it expects only a two digit year, it expects that those two digits are the last two digits and automatically prepends the first two digits of the current century - ergo, the `20` from `2015` becomes `2020`. Let's be clear, this is not a bug in `momentjs` logic, you told it what to expect, and then you gave it something else.